# Instrumentation Tools for Collecting Data in DRAM accesses

Tags: memory, data, trace, instrumentation, dram

We can use instrumentation tools, such as [Pin tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool.html), to collect memory accesses of an application running on a system. The type (read or write) and memory address can be collected. How about data? Can we use Pin tool to collect data? If not, are there any instrumentation tools to collect data too?

Comment: While some of us do know a little about software (firmware) here, [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) is primarily for *hardware* engineering. Your question may be better-suited to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).  [Checking there](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intel+pin), there seems to be 579 matches to "intel pin" - perhaps start there.

Comment: @rdtsc I don't know why but I cannot ask questions on stack overflow

Comment: @ArghavanMohammadhassani - Hi, You said: "*I don't know why but I cannot ask questions on stack overflow*". I have contacted a helpful moderator on Stack Overflow. Unfortunately you have been deleting your questions which were not well-received by site members there. Therefore you have triggered the error message explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997). That also means I cannot migrate your question to SO. Personally I think your question is off-topic here, but we'll see how the community votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution to obtain data. Since we have obtained the address of memory location, we can use PIN_SafeCopy() to copy the content of that address to a variable. Here is the declaration for PIN_SafeCopy() in `/<pin_dir>/source/include/pin/gen/pin_client.PH`:

```
extern size_t PIN_SafeCopy(VOID* dst, const VOID* src, size_t size);
 /*! @ingroup PIN_CONTROL
 * Copy the specified number of bytes from a source memory region to a destination memory region.
 * The function guarantees safe return to the caller even if the source or destination
 * regions are inaccessible (entirely or partially).
 *
 * Tools should use this function to ensure safe access to the original content of the
 * application's memory. For example, on Windows, Pin replaces certain TEB fields when running
 * analysis routines in the tool. If the tool accesses these fields directly, it would see the
 * values assigned by Pin rather than the original ones. On the contrary, PIN_SafeCopy() always
 * reads and modifies the original application's values of these fields.
 *
 * This function can be used in any thread, including any internal thread spawned by the tool.
 *
 * @param[out] dst      destination region
 * @param[in]  src      region to copy from
 * @param[in]  size     number of bytes to copy
 *
 * @return  Number of bytes successfully copied from the source to the destination region.
 */
```